# Mouse/touch coordinates in wrong location HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, responsive-design

I'm having trouble with my HTML canvas, was working fine in its experimental stage however once I brought it into my proper development the mouse coordinates have become completely wonky, It does draw, however not in the correct position i.e. I click and drag to draw a line, that line is the draw further down within the canvas. I'm just looking to fix the coordinates in so the mouse cursor draws exactly where it should be.

Below is my code, In order to get a sense of what Im talking about be sure to resize the browser window as the website is mobile specific. Thank you any help would be much appreciated

Ive tried using `getXY` functions but I already have a variable name after that but it didn't work. I also tried various styling techniques but to no avail

```js
function init() {
  // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
  canvas = document.getElementById('c');
}

function midPointBtw(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / 2,
    y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / 2
  };
}

function getPattern() {
  return ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
}

var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = getPattern();
};

img.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/rF2R0GRY/dick2.png";
var isDrawing, points = [];

var getXY = function(e) {
  var source = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;

  return {
    x: source.clientX,
    y: source.clientY
  };
};

var startDrawing = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push(getXY(e));
  e.preventDefault();
};


var keepDrawing = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  points.push(getXY(e));
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  var p1 = points[0];
  var p2 = points[1];

  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);

  for (var i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var midPoint = midPointBtw(p1, p2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i + 1];
  }

  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  e.preventDefault();
};

var stopDrawing = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points = [];
};

el.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchmove', keepDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousemove', keepDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);

function clearCanvas(canvas, ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath()
}

init();
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Geoma Regular Demo;
  src: url(Geoma Regular Demo.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Geoma Demo;
  src: url(Geoma Light demo.otf);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  html,
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid #0BF446;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#clearbutton {
  background-color: #04A12B;
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Geoma Demo;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#footer1 {
  background-color: #00671A;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#about {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Geoma Demo;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="350" height="500"></canvas>
<input type="submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" id="clearbutton" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
<footer id="footer1">
  <a href="" id="about">About Elemental</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: I have adjusted your presented code so that it will run in a runnable snippet.  I also changed your `event` variable usages to `e` because it was causing a syntax error because, from your question, it seemed that your code is already running and the crux of your issue is the localization of the click events.  If this was **not** the issue, please feel free to revert my edits so that we can focus on the actual issue.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to localize your click event to be relative to the canvas element.  You can do this by getting the `top` and `left` out of `el.getBoundingClientRect()` and using them to adjust the `x` and `y` value of your click event.  See below, most of the work was done in the `getXY` function.

```js
function init() {
  // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
  canvas = document.getElementById('c');
}

function midPointBtw(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / 2,
    y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / 2
  };
}

function getPattern() {
  return ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
}

var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = getPattern();
};

img.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/rF2R0GRY/dick2.png";
var isDrawing, points = [];

var getXY = function(e) {
  var source = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = source;
  const {
    left,
    top
  } = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  const x = clientX - left;
  const y = clientY - top;

  return {
    x,
    y
  };
};

var startDrawing = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push(getXY(e));
  e.preventDefault();
};


var keepDrawing = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  points.push(getXY(e));
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  var p1 = points[0];
  var p2 = points[1];

  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);

  for (var i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var midPoint = midPointBtw(p1, p2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i + 1];
  }

  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  e.preventDefault();
};

var stopDrawing = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points = [];
};

el.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchmove', keepDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mousemove', keepDrawing);

el.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
el.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);

function clearCanvas(canvas, ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath()
}

init();
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Geoma Regular Demo;
  src: url(Geoma Regular Demo.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Geoma Demo;
  src: url(Geoma Light demo.otf);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  html,
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid #0BF446;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#clearbutton {
  background-color: #04A12B;
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Geoma Demo;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#footer1 {
  background-color: #00671A;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#about {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Geoma Demo;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="350" height="500"></canvas>
<input type="submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" id="clearbutton" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
<footer id="footer1">
  <a href="" id="about">About Elemental</a>
</footer>
```